# How can I create an object in .ascx?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms, accessor

I've wrapped the asp:DropDown control so that I can create a lot of instances of it, all of which using the same additional functionality. I want to be able to create this object completely in the .ascx rather than using the code behind. I'm almost there, with the exception of the ListItems.

Here's what I have thus far, can anyone help me to figure out how to get the list items to populate?

```
<Control:DropDown ID="choice" runat="server" DropDownListLabel="Some Choice:"
QueryString="choice" SelectedIndex="0" ListItems='<%# new ListItemCollection(){
new ListItem("<no filter>", "-1"), new ListItem("Yes", "y"), new ListItem("No", "n")
} %>' />
```

Everything is working, with the exception of the ListItems, although the list items do work as expected from code behind. Any help on how I can get the ListItems accessor to call properly?

Thanks in advance,
Brett

Comment: What @Prescott said, but if your goal is to just pass a list of things to a `DropDownList` it would be a lot cleaner to just have a `string` property and parse it. That is rather than using an ugly scriptlet  that creates a bunch of objects like that, give it a string (e.g. in JSON format) like `"{ ["<no filter>","-1"],["Yes","y"],["No","n"] }"` and have your subclassed DropDownList turn that into `ListItems`

Comment: @jamietre is absolutely correct as an alternative. You could also do this by using my method below and adding an additional property that takes the ListItems in some format that you can then parse. I think it really depends on how you are generating the items. If they are from a database, it might be a quick shortcut to put a method/function that is specific to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should have created your control to inherit from `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList` then override rendering and add properties that you want extra, this would allow you to something like the following:

```
<Control:DropDown id="mycontrol" runat="server" DropDownListLabel="Some Choice:" ..>
    <asp:ListItem Text="<no filter" value="-1" />
    ...
</Control:DropDown>
```

Where DropDownListLabel is an added property. Of course in your case you'd add QueryString as a property as well